# How to abort threads when application window is closing

Tags: wpf, multithreading, abort

I have a WPF application with threads.  How do I abort all threads when closing the application?

Comment: As long as the threads are background threads, you don't have to do anything special.

Comment: If they are background threads, then I think they'll close when the application exits. What kind are they?

Comment: `Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Start));` This is ma Thread inicjalization. When I close application, Visual Studio is still running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you create the thread, set the [`IsBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) property to `true`.

```
Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Start));
th.IsBackground = true;
th.Start();
```